# How to enforce method usage in Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to enforce my method of a class in my Android Studio project so that if I don't use it (which will give you warning *"method x is never used"*) my project **don't compile**. How to achive that?

Comment: "method x is never used" will not stop AS to compile.

Comment: It won't, what I need to do is to stop AS from compiling my project if I had an unused method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Analysis__Code_Inspections.html.

Intellij has code inspections, and it should be possible to change that "not called" part to error.

But note: this isn't necessarily a good approach. Depending on your context (for example team size), there might be often situations where person A adds a new method that gets used by person B *after* A released code. And do think usage in test code is sufficient?!

So: be careful about introducing build breaks. Rather keep track of all warnings you have on your project, and try to keep that number close to 0.

Comment: Is there any way to enforce it on a particular method, not all of them?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, and again: I think you are investing your time and energy in the wrong place. Why do you think you need your build to fail when a specific method isnt used?

Comment: It just that I need to make sure to clean up some resource in a class

Comment: Now assume your method X is called by method Y. Are you sure that Y is called?! Still sounds like you are going in the wrong direction. But thinking ... maybe maybe maybe https://www.archunit.org/ has something that allows you to specify such a condition.

Comment: I never thought of that before. Now I see why it would be a bad practice, thanks.